# "The ActiveX control "{CCB90042-B81E-11D2-AB74-0040054C3719}" is not registered on this computer."

Tags: activex, driver, visual-c++-6, opos

I got a VC6 program about OPOS driver from my company, which was left by ex-employee. I built it and got executable file successfully. I ran it and nothing happened. But it's supposed to show a form with some buttons & other kinds of controls inside it. According to the original designer, it works. But it doesn't work. Besides, I got message usually when browsing the resource or running the program: "The ActiveX control "{CCB90042-B81E-11D2-AB74-0040054C3719}" is not registered on this computer.  Register the control and try again.

I am not familiar with ActiveX. How can I do to register so that the program can run successfully.

My platform is POSReady 2009, which is close to Windows XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a file called `OPOSCashDrawer.ocx`, which [appears to be the file associated with that GUID](http://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=en&sl=ko&u=http://www.windowactivex.com/bbs/board.php%3Fq%3Dopos-cashdrawer-control-1-11-000-public-by-crm-rcs-dayton-ccb90042-ct&prev=search). You'll need to call `regsvr32` to register that file:

```
regsvr32 OPOSCashDrawer.ocx
```

[How to register an ActiveX control (.ocx) manually](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/146219)

Comment: I did it (regsvr32 OPOSCashDrawer.ocx) successfully. I rebuilt my program and ran it again. I still found nothing happened. It's supposed a form with some controls must be shown.

Comment: @StanHuangatTaiwan: If nothing happened, does that mean it's fixed the "ActiveX control not registered" error you were getting previously?

Comment: Richard Deeming,
   I am not sure now, need time to verify it. I will update it then.
Thanks any way

Comment: I think this issue must be done, although this program still didn't show its GUI. It should has nothing to do with ActiveX any way. Thanks Richard Deeming very much.

Comment: I've got the reason why after registering ActiveX control, the application program couldn't still show it's GUI. It's because I didn't install OPOS dll & CCO. After I did them, the application program runs well.